# Recall the names of functions used in a long MMA code

Tags: functions, programming

Suppose you have a very long `code` in which many new functions are created. For efficient programming, very short and easily iterated function names are preferred.

For example,

```
runningFast[x_]:=x^2
```

can be named as

```
rf[x_]:=x^2
```

Obviously, the latter function `rf[]` is preferable in such example as:

```
k[y_]:=rf[x]^3+Sqrt[rf[x]]+Log[rf[x]]+...
```

because it is easy to write. However, if I come back to the same function later on, I might not remember what `rf[x]` does.

**Question**

Given a notebook, is there any way to keep track the function names with some explanatory note so that I can recall the names at will?

Comment: If you expect to modify/maintain something you have written later on, "because it is easy to write" ranks quite low on the list of reasons to pick a function name. More so if your memory is not the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a usage message

```
rf::usage = "rf[x] is short for runningFast[x]";
```

when you type `rf` you can click the help button that pops up as you type, or evaluate

```
?rf
```

to get the usage message.

A tip from @m_goldberg in the comments is to put the usage statements in initialization cells in an auxiliary notebook, and include that notebook in your working notebook with a call to `Needs`.

Comment: Yes, it is an answer to my question. I wonder if there is any  way to keep all of the `usage messages` in a separate notebook linked to the notebook where they are created. The reason is that I like to have an uncluttered `notebook` (without explanatory notes) and retrieve the names not as single elements but retrieve the entire notebook where the names are stored like a separate `window` open when I create other names..

Comment: @TugrulTemel. You can put the the usage message definitions in an auxiliary notebook. Make all the definition cells initialization cells. Put a `Needs` function call at beginning of you working notebook to load the messages. Make the cell with the `Needs` call an initialization cell as well.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Thanks for the very useful piece of information. I want to accept your comment as an answer, how can I do that?

Comment: @TugrulTemel. You can't accept a comment, but you can accept the the answer it is attached to, which is what I recommend. I made my remarks a comment so as not to set up a rival answer to this one.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @m_goldberg: I added your suggestion to the body of my answer (with attribution).